# How to add white spaces inside parenthesis when editing a PHP Formatter Profile?

Tags: php, aptana, code-formatting

I would like to know how to add white spaces inside parenthesis, when editing a PHP Formatter Profile on Aptana Studio 3.

I enjoy using this style:

```
if ( $var == 3 ).
```

But, while editing a profile, I wasn't able to find a option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This one actually have a ticket that will deal with it - see http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1712
Once implemented, you will be able to control the spaces before and after the parenthesis (and also by type of parenthesis).
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

in the formatter menu: white_space-->control statements->if else and tick all the options